# How to get a method to read a file input in Java?

Tags: java, file-io, methods, io

If I have the following code:

```
public Bicycle(int maxSpeed, String brand, int numOfGears, String name) {
```

And I wanted it to read a .txt file that had 1 line of information that was as follows: "3, Huffy, 6, Charles" and return an object that contains that info - how would be the best way to do that?

Would doing the following be enough to do that?

```
public Bicycle(int maxSpeed, String brand, int numOfGears, String name) {
    Bicycle newBike = new Bicycle (read information from file here);
}
```

Please let me know if I can clarify the question any further.

Comment: [This](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/charstreams.html) will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is approximate code to read single line

```
File file = new File("test.txt");
FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(reader);
String line = buf.readLine();
String[] tokens = line.split(",");
int number = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0].trim());
String name = tokens[1].trim();
```

You will need to adjust path to text file and handle possible `FileNotFoundException`, also `IOException` for buf.readLine()`buf.readLine()`. Once you have string you split it. You can extract variables and use them. Be sure that data in file matches expected pattern - so additional exception handling is required. Once you got all four variables you can construct your `Bicycle`.

Comment: This is the right thing to go with with standard Java.  You may want to name the FileReader 'fileReader' and the BufferedReader as 'bufferedReader', to avoid confusion.

Comment: You'll also probably need this in a try/catch block, for exceptions, and should look into how to *close* a FileReader when you're done with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `commons.io` library

```
    String s = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("{filePath}"));
    String[] words = s.trim().split(",");
    object1.setNumber(words[0]);
    object1.setName(words[1]);
    object2.setNumber(words[2]);
    object2.setName(words[3]);
```